# Python How to get variable input to run with subprocess.Popen from iteration

Tags: python, subprocess, nmap

The code below iterates over a list with http scripts. The variable should then be input into the `x` variable. Output is printed to a file. But file produces output stating `script="`, have tried other variations but always with errors.

```
with open("nmap_http_output.txt", "w") as f: 
    for x in scripts:   # iterate over http scripts
            print(x)  # for debugging purposes - this prints
            print(ip) # for debugging purposes - this prints
            nmap_http_ps = subprocess.Popen(['nmap', '-p80', ' --script=', x, ip], stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
            output = nmap_http_ps.communicate()
            print(output)
```

Output is:

```
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.30 seconds
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-18 08:51 CST
Failed to resolve " --script=".
Failed to resolve """.
Unable to split netmask from target expression: "/usr/share/nmap/scripts/http-auth-finder.nse"
Failed to resolve """.
```

Comment: before you look for inputs you may like to consider:
`nmap_http_ps.join()`
which waits for the subprocess to complete.  It is also possible to specify a timeout in `join()` and take appropriate action if 'nmap' has not completed within the timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you got the parameters for `Popen` wrong.

```
with open("nmap_http_output.txt", "w") as f: 
    for x in scripts:   # iterate over http scripts
        print(x)  # for debugging purposes - this prints
        print(ip) # for debugging purposes - this prints
        nmap_http_ps = subprocess.Popen(
            ['nmap', '-p', '80', ' --script=%s' % x, ip], stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
            )
        output = nmap_http_ps.communicate()
        print(output)
```

`Popen` expects a list of "elements" of a command, but you have to be careful in terms of what constitutes an "element". I believe (can not test it right now) that you must fix two things:

- `'-p'` becomes `'-p', '80'` (two elements - a switch and a parameter)
- `' --script=', x` becomes `'--script=%s' % x` (instead of two elements, this should be just one - and there is also a leading space too much)

Comment: s-m-e                                                                                                        looks like that did it                                                                                     1) ''-p' becomes '-p', '80' (two elements - a switch and a parameter)'                                                                             2) changed ' --script=', x   ->  '--script={}'.format(x), ip                                        Thanks